# Value of input undefined inside a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is a part of my partial view.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is a part of my controller -

```
self.password = document.getElementById("password");
        self.confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmPassword");

       angular.element(self.confirmPassword).on("input", function () {
            var closest = self.confirmPassword.closest('div');
            console.log(self.password.value); //undefined
            if(self.password.value != self.confirmPassword.value) {
                    closest.classList.remove("has-success");
                    closest.className += " has-error";
            } else {
                closest.classList.remove("has-error");
                closest.className += " has-success";   
            };
        });
```

Why is `self.password.value` undefined inside the function. My final goal is to add the class `has-error` if password is not equal to confirm password and add the class `has-success` if password is equal to confirm password.

Comment: check this. works fine for me https://plnkr.co/edit/9GwoINvY4Gl5ZBvBo19Q?p=preview though I would suggest to use data binding and directives instead of accessing element using `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of errors in your code.

- First a controller shouldn't access a view, until it's the link function
  of a directive.
- Next the event "input" doesn't exists. If you want to
  have some custom class in your view, use ng-class
  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass
- If you want to use validation of forms in angular, read this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms